# How do you programmatically get a list of all common parameters?

Tags: powershell, reflection, parameters

Powershell Cmdlets inherit a bunch of [common parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx).  Some cmdlets I write end up with predicates that depend on which parameters are actually bound.  This often leads to filtering out common parameters which means you need a list of common parameter names.

I also expect there to be difference in the list of common parameters from one version of powershell to another.

All of this boils down to this question:

How do you programmatically determine the list of common parameters?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about these static properties?

```
[System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet]::CommonParameters
[System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet]::OptionalCommonParameters
```

The existing common parameters is the combination of both lists:

> **CommonParameters**: Lists the common parameters that are added by the PowerShell engine to any cmdlet that derives from PSCmdlet.
>
> **OptionalCommonParameters**: Lists the common parameters that are added by the PowerShell engine when a cmdlet defines additional capabilities (SupportsShouldProcess, SupportsTransactions)

i.e. All of them can exist, but the optional ones only exists if the cmdlet supports them. For detailed info see [Cmdlet Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)

Comment: FWIW, this works for Powershell 4.0, 3.0, but no 2.0.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
function Get-CommonParameterNames
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Keys
}
```

Comment: I think it worth to change `(Get-Command Get-egCommonParameterNames)` to `$MyInvocation.MyCommand`, so that you are immune to function name change or to situations where `Get-Command Get-egCommonParameterNames` will resolve not to your command. And you also does not need `process` block here.

Comment: @PetSerAl Done.

Comment: You do not need `Get-Command` here. `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Keys`