# Getting bound parameters that are not "common parameters"?

Tags: powershell

simple example

```
function Verb-Noun
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        $Param1,

        [int]
        $Param2
    )

    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {
        $PSBoundParameters
    }
    End
    {
    }
}

Verb-Noun 'some param value' -Verbose
```

ofc returns

```
Key     Value           
---     -----           
Verbose True            
Param1  some param value
```

so, how to get all bound parameters but not the common ones/provided by [CmdletBinding()]? ...without verbose in the abobe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a specific built in way to do that, but you could remove the common parameters from the hashtable. To programmatically list the common parameters, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29956201/3905079).

I'm using the [PowerShell 2 answer from that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956326/3905079), so we could do this:

```
Function Get-egCommonParameterNames
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    process
    {
        (Get-Command Get-egCommonParameterNames).Parameters.Keys
    }
}

$myParams = [hashtable]$PSBoundParameters
Get-egCommonParameterNames | ForEach-Object { $myParams.Remove($_) }
```

[Do note that each step of a pipeline could have different bound parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34033842/3905079).

Comment: @JaquelineVanek just fixed up some errors in it, should be working now.

Comment: it's fine, got the idea= I was stuck in some lousy construct of mines :D
 $param_names += (Get-Variable -Name $Parameter.Values.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Name

Comment: Why not `[System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet]::CommonParameters`?

Comment: @PetSerAl that's fine too, but apparently doesn't work in PowerShell 2 (see the linked question). I went for the most supported option.

Comment: +1 @briantist.  It's probably worth mentioning [the surprising behavior of `$PSBoundParameters` in the pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34032902/1404637).